# NestJS import issue within the framework with Node 18

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, nestjs, tsconfig

I have really strange errors after update Node from 14 to 18.18.2 LTS.
I'm using NestJS in my backend and after mentioned update I noticed a lot of errors like:

```js
/backend/src/common/entities/base.service.ts:40
    @Inject() private fileService: FileService;
                                   ^
ReferenceError: file_service_1 is not defined
    at BaseObjectManager (/backend/src/common/entities/base.service.ts:40:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/backend/src/modules/object-manager/user/user.service.ts:26:64)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/backend/src/modules/object-manager/user/user.controller.ts:11:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
```

I can easily fix it with changing the absolute import path to relative one:

Example:

from

```
import { User } from 'src/modules/user/entities/user.entity';
```

to

```
import { User } from '../../../../user/entities/user.entity';
```

Ok, I know the solution but the problem here is that I have to change 1200 files... so it's not possible to do it manually.

My tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "preserveWatchOutput": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/**", "dist/**"]
}
```

Have you any other solution?
I just highlight, that the mix of relative and absolute paths works properly with Node 14.
I tried a lot of solutions like change the Nest version, change the tsconfig file etc. but I didn't find solution.

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use typescript [path aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/paths.html) to map that `src/*` into `./src/*`

Comment: I tried:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
        "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
}
```

and it's not working :(

Comment: are you using nestjs cli to build your code?

Comment: No, everything manually

Comment: By "manually" do you mean you are running `tsc` yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "ts-imports-fixer" that can help automate the process of updateing your import paths in the codebase.

But this a correct tsconfig.json path mapping:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "paths": {
    "@src/*": ["src/*"]
  }
  // other options
 }
}
```

import

```
import { User } form '@src/modules/user/entitied/user.entity';
```

Comment: Also tried, no results :/

Comment: Weird, try to node 16.15.0 this was the previous node lts. see if that works and then you have to look for problems in the newer node lts